# Calculate the remainder of 5 to the power of 120

Tags: number-theory

I was going through [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/246424/fermats-little-theorem)

And the first [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/246430/134937) made me think.

> Fermat's Little Theorem tells us that **$5^{18} = 1$ mod $19$.**
>
> Observe next that $5^{120} = (5^{18})^6 \cdot 5^{12}$.
>
> Reducing modulo $19$, we have $5^{120} = 1^{6} \cdot 5^{12} = 5^{12}$
>   mod $19$.
>
> All that's left now is to calculate $5^{12}$ mod $19$, which can be
>   done quickly by brute force.
>
> For example, $5^4 = 625 = 608 + 17 = 32\cdot19 + 17 = -2$ mod $19$.
>
> Then $5^{12} = (5^4)^3 = (-2)^3 = -8$ mod $19$, which is the same as
>   $11$ mod $19$.
>
> And there you have it: the remainder is $11$.

1. How to get the first line, out of nothing? I mean what is the tricks? How to come up with the number 18 in the first line?
2. I didn't understand this two line. I mean how they are calculated -

> For example, $5^4 = 625 = 608 + 17 = 32\cdot19 + 17 = -2$ mod $19$.
>
> Then $5^{12} = (5^4)^3 = (-2)^3 = -8$ mod $19$, which is the same as
>   $11$ mod $19$.

Comment: It would be better if you actually wrote out your question instead of making us try to figure out what you are asking. In this case, I think you are asking why is $5^{18}\equiv 1\pmod{19}$, and the answer, *as that answerer stated,* is that it is a direct application of Fermat's Little Theorem. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_little_theorem

Comment: My question is how to get the value of p, so that 5 to the power 18 is 1.

Comment: So you should say "For which prime $p$ do we have $5^{18}=1 \pmod p$ ?"

Comment: Everything you desire is here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_little_theorem
This could help also
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_theorem

Comment: Note that you are given the modulus $19$ (which is a prime) in the question. So that is what you work with. $19-1=18$ - see a comment I made on one of your previous questions for the "mod" language. Note that the form $a^{p-1}\equiv 1$ is normally used for little Fermat, rather than $a^p=a$ which you quoted in another previous question. That is because the $p-1$ form is often more useful, especially in questions like the one you have highlighted.

Comment: That is okay, but I haven't calculated that $5^{!8}$ is 1. What if this doesn't satisfy?

Comment: But this **is** true, by Fermat's little theorem (see the link above).

Comment: $5^{18}=1 \pmod{19}$
And as the theorem states $a^{p-1}=1 \pmod{p}$
for every prime number p and integer a

Comment: @ah11950 What if that I was asked to calculate the remainder of $5^{120}$ when it is divided with 13? Then will it be that $5^{12}$  = 1 is true?

Comment: Yes. For any prime $p$ and $a$ with $p \nmid a$, we have $a^{p-1} \equiv 1\; (\textrm{mod}\; p)$. This is precisely the statement of Fermat's little theorem...so it of course holds when $a=5$ and $p=13$ too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my comment for why you use $18$ and how it relates to your previous questions.

So we want to know the remainder of $5^{120}$ when divided by $19$ and we write this as $5^{120} \mod 19$.

We know that because $(5,19)=1$ (they have no common factor greater than $1$) we have $5^{18}\equiv 1 \mod 19$ - This is because of Fermat's Little Theorem applied with $p=19$.

Since $120=18\cdot 6 + 12$, we have $5^{120}=(5^{18})^65^{12} \equiv 5^{12}\mod 19$

In a comment on one of your previous questions I noted that we could do arithmetic modulo $19$ without having to keep track of multiples of $19$  (in fact my comment was for any $p$ - and it works with a little care for any integer - division can go wrong for non-primes) - we are only interested in the remainders. We are now looking for the remainder for $5^{12}$ which we have shown is the same as that for $5^{120}$ by application of little Fermat.

Now we note that $5^{12}=(5^4)^3$. Noticing that $5^4=625$ we can get rid of some extra multiples of $19$ because $625= 32\cdot 19+ 17=33\cdot 19 -2 \equiv -2 \mod 19$. Since we want small numbers to simplify the arithmetic as much as possible we choose $-2$.

So the remainder for $5^4$ is the same as that for $-2$, and the remainder for $(5^4)^3$ is the same as for $(-2)^3=-8$.

Now there is a near convention that we choose the smallest possible positive remainder (there occasions where another choice is useful*). So we note that $-8=11-1\cdot 19\equiv 11 \mod 19$ to finish off.

I suggest that now you have asked a few questions about this, you try some examples for yourself. You need to get used to the language a bit - you will have noticed how naturally it comes to the people who have been posting answers and comments - and how much longer I had to make this answer to avoid using it.

*eg some proofs of quadratic reciprocity