# A modular arithmetic exponent problem

Tags: modular-arithmetic, exponentiation, problem-solving

I was learning modular arithmetic and there was a problem that
$4^{62} \equiv \ ? \pmod{7}$ The solution was to find the mods of the same number's exponents starting from one until the result equals to one because after one it repeats. Like this
\begin{align*}
4^1 & \equiv 4 \pmod{7}\\
4^2 & \equiv 2 \pmod{7}\\
4^3 & \equiv 1 \pmod{7}
\end{align*}

Then it repeats three steps. So we find $62  \pmod{3}$ which congruent to $2$ and this is the answer. Then I wondered why it just starts to repeat after one. I tried other numbers too, they just repeat after one. Is there any trick?

Comment: The *trick* is called Fermat's Little Theorem.  See [this related Question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/246424/fermats-little-theorem), out of hundreds of questions and answers on the topic here.

Comment: @hardmath Oh, thanks :) Appreciated!

Comment: At a guess your course materials are motivating the introduction of this important theorem.  Note that $7$ being a prime means that any integer $x$ not divisible by $7$ will satisfy $x^6 \equiv 1 \pmod{7}$, but $4 = 2^2$, so the "period" of repetition for powers of $4$ is shortened (by half) from $6$ to $3$.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is simply the law of exponents: since $4^3\equiv 1\pmod7$, for $n>3$, we have
$$4^{n}=4^3\cdot4^{n-3}\equiv 1\cdot4^{n-3}=4^{n-3}\pmod 7$$

By induction, if $n=3q+r\quad(0\le r<3)$, we have $4^{n}\equiv 4^r$, i.e.
$$4^{n}\equiv 4^{n\bmod3}\pmod7.$$