# Evaluate $2488^{2016}\equiv ?\pmod 7$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Evaluate $2488^{2016}\equiv ?\pmod 7$. How do I solve these kind of questions ? Is that modular exponentiation or modular arithmetic ?

Comment: @StrangeBrew Don't you mean $7^x\equiv0\pmod{7}$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A modular arithmetic exponent problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1443420/a-modular-arithmetic-exponent-problem)

Answer (score 4):

Two key facts are:

- $2488 \equiv 3 \bmod 7$
- $a^6 \equiv 1 \bmod 7$, whenever $7$ does not divide $a$.

Answer (score 1):

Fermat's little theorem states that if $p$ is a prime and $a \not\equiv 0 \pmod p$, then $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$. So if you want to compute large powers modulo a prime, Fermat's little theorem is very handy.